# "The student said that birds can fly"

Tags: reported-speech, backshifting

The script, which checks grammar, explains next.

It appears that the verb **can** in the dependent clause uses the wrong tense.

Should I rewrite the sentence in this way?

> The student said that birds **could** fly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What the script is doing is called "backshifting".

In this case it is optional, since you can be quite confident that if you asked the student again, he would still say "birds can fly".

If you asked the student if he was able to go to the pub yesterday, and he said, "I can go to the pub".  Then today when you report it you would say, "The student said that he could go to the pub."  This is because it was true yesterday, but might not be true today, so a past tense makes more sense.

Backshifting is optional when applied to a statement that remains true today, it is more common when applied to a statement that might not be true today. But he script can't tell the difference, since the script can't understand the sentence.  It doesn't know that bird can fly.